# Should I be prepared for fault when WSDL doesn't define it for operation?

Tags: web-services, input, wsdl, fault

I'd like to know if I should be prepared for faults when WSDL doesn't define them for an operation. To be more specific, there's a WSDL with operation defined with input only (see below). For me, this means that I shouldn't be prepared for any fault messages and after sending request, I may go further without looking at HTTP response. Am I right with this?

```
<wsdl:operation name="someOperationName">
  <wsdl:input message="someOperationMessage" name="someOperationRequest"></wsdl:input>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Best regards,
szeldon

Answer (score 0):

You should always be prepared for faults returned from web services.  Whether faults are declared in a WSDL document is a function of the service provider and the nature of the call.  Ideally, if a fault situation can be reasonably expected and may be addressed by the client (e.g. validation exception), the generated fault should be declared and the client application can tailor a response around that fault.

The value of including a fault declaration in a WSDL for a situation which the client is unlikely to resolve (e.g. back-end database failure) is in the documentation (nice to know what kinds of faults might be returned) more than the functionality.

In either case, the HTTP response should add to the information provided by any fault message and there may still be some cases where a failure might be indicated via HTTP response code with no fault returned at all (server failure, for example).